If $a \le b \le c \le d$, proving that $ (a+b+c+d)^2 \ge 8(ad+bc)$
We can prove that $(a+b+c+d)^2\ge 8(ad+bc),~\text{if}~ a \le b \le c \le d,$ by considering $f(x)=(x-a)(x-d)+(x-b)(x-c).$
As $f(a)>0 ~\& ~f(b)<0$, $f(x)=0$ will have one root in $(a,b)$. Similarly, as $f(c)<0~\&~ f(d)>0$, $f(x)=0$ will have one real root in $(c,d).$ Hence $f(x)=0$ will have two real roots, consequently the discriminant condition gives
$$(a+b+c+d)^2 \ge 8(ad+bc).~~~~~~~(*)$$ Equality holds when $a=b=c=d.$
The question is how else we can prove this inequality (*)?

One way is to expand and use rearrangement inequality and AM-GM. (The first applies to any reals; for the second you need to consider absolute values, but that only works in your favour.)
$$2ab+2cd\geq 2ad+2cb$$
$$2ac+2bd\geq 2ad+2bc$$
$$a^2+d^2\geq 2|ad|\geq 2ad$$
$$b^2+c^2\geq 2|bc|\geq 2bc$$

From $(x+y)^2 \geqslant 4xy,$ we have
$$(a+b+c+d)^2 \geqslant 4(a+c)(b+d).$$
Therefore, we need to prove
$$(a+c)(b+d) - 2(ad+bc) = (c-a)(d-b) \geqslant 0.$$
Done.

@Andreas Are you sure? $(x+y)^2-4xy = (x-y)^2 \geqslant 0.$
